# Pick a specific value in a program output (Bash)

Tags: linux, string, bash, sed

I'm running LIBSVM in linux terminal called by a C program. Ok, i need to pick the output but the format is the following

```
Accuracy = 80% (24/30) (classification)
```

I need to pick only the "80" value as an integer. I tried with sed and came to this command:

```
sed 's/[^0-9^'%']//g' 'f' >> f
```

This is filtering all integers in the output and, thus, isn't working yet, so I need help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try `grep` in PCRE mode (`-P`), printing only the matched parts (`-o`), with a [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
 $ echo "Accuracy = 80% (24/30) (classification)" | grep -Po '[0-9]+(?=%)'
 80
```

The regexp:

```
[0-9]  # match a digit
+      # one or more times
(?=%)  # assert that the digits are followed by a %
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very trivial with `awk`. Identify the column you need and strip the '%' sign from it. The `/^Accuracy/` regex ensures that the action is only performed on the lines starting with Accuracy. You don't need it if your file only contains one line.

```
awk '/^Accuracy/{sub(/%/,"");print $3}' inputFile
```

Alternatively, you can set space and `%` as field separators and do

```
awk -F'[ %]' '/^Accuracy/{print $3}' inputFile
```

If you want to do it with `sed` then you can try something like:

```
sed '/^Accuracy/s/.* \(.*\)%.*/\1/' inputFile
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nr '/^Accuracy = ([^%]*)%.*/s//\1/p' file
```